# React: how use component with use custom Props interface with 'react-redux' connection decorator

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I'm use React with typescript and i cant use my component with 'react-redux' connection decorator. I have are component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import State from '../../models/State';
import { showPopup } from '../../actions/popup.actions';

import IconButton from '../IconButton/IconButton.component';
import Page from '../Page/Page.component';
import Popup from '../Popup/Popup.component';

interface Props {
   popups: string[];
   showPopup: Function;
   hidePopup: Function;
}

class AccountsPage extends React.Component {
    props: Props;

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Page>
                <div className="page__header">
                    <IconButton icon="add" onClick={() => 1}>Добавить</IconButton>
                </div>
                <div className="page__content">
                     <button onClick={() => this.props.showPopup()}>Show popup</button>
                </div>
                {
                    this.isPopupVisible ? 
                        <Popup onClose={() => this.props.hidePopup()}>
                            <div>Hi!</div>
                        </Popup> :
                        null
                }
            </Page>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(
    (state: State) => ({
        popups: state.popups
    }),
    (dispatch: Function) => ({
        showPopup: (pageName: string) => dispatch(showPopup(pageName))
        hidePopup: (pageName: string) => dispatch(hidePopup(pageName))
    })
)(AccountsPage);
```

and i'm get an error:

```
(62,3): Argument of type 'typeof AccountsPage' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<{ popups: string[]; } & { showPopup: (pageName: string) => any; hidePopup: (pageNam...'.
Type 'typeof AccountsPage' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<{ popups: string[]; } & { showPopup: (pageName: string) => any; hidePopup: (pa...'.
Type 'typeof AccountsPage' provides no match for the signature '(props: { popups: string[]; } & { showPopup: (pageName: string) => any; hidePopup: (pageName: string) => any; } & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any> | null'.
```

If I'm change `props: Props` to `props: any` all works fine, how can I change my Props interface for fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fully typed example:

```
interface DispatchProps {
    hidePopup: (pageName: string) => void;
    showPopup: (pageName: string) => void;
}

interface StateProps {
    popups: State['popups'];
}

type Props = DispatchProps & StateProps;

class AccountsPage extends React.Component<Props> {

    isPopupVisible: boolean;

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Page>
                <div className="page__header">
                    <IconButton icon="add" onClick={() => 1}>Добавить</IconButton>
                </div>
                <div className="page__content">
                    <button onClick={() => this.props.showPopup()}>Show popup</button>
                </div>
                {
                    this.isPopupVisible ?
                        <Popup onClose={() => this.props.hidePopup()}>
                            <div>Hi!</div>
                        </Popup> :
                        null
                }
            </Page>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(
    (state: State): StateProps => ({
        popups: state.popups
    }),
    (dispatch: Function): DispatchProps => ({
        showPopup: (pageName: string) => dispatch(showPopup(pageName)),
        hidePopup: (pageName: string) => dispatch(hidePopup(pageName))
    })
)(AccountsPage);
```

It looks like `isPopupVisible` should maybe be a state variable but I'm not sure, so left it as it is. You are also calling `hidePopup()` and `showPopup()` without `pageName` name in your example so they will cause an error until changed.

I'm not sure how `hidePopup()` and `showPopup()` are defined in your code, but you could potentially have this for `DispatchProps` instead:

```
interface DispatchProps {
    hidePopup: typeof hidePopup;
    showPopup: typeof showPopup;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your call to `React.Component` with TypeScript needs to specify `Props` as a type argument like so:

```
class AccountsPage extends React.Component<Props, {}> {

}
```